# SQL Server Select query to exclude similar rows based on the length of one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a table that has data similar to:

```
key1, key2, col1, col2, col3
1,    2,    1,    10,   'bla'
2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla2'
2,    1,    2,    10,   'bla'
```

keys 1 and 2 are a composite key.

I would like a query that returns:

```
key1, key2, col1, col2, col3
2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla2'
2,    1,    2,    10,   'bla'
```

So no two rows have the same value for both col1 and col2. And the col3 value returned is the one with the longest length.

I think this must be simple - but I cant workout the solution.

Many thanks, Paul

Comment: What is the query you tried?

Comment: You didn't even care to [create SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: The sample data I entered is correct. I want to exclude the first row (1,2,1,10,'bla') from the result set as the second row has the same values for col1 and col2, but the text contained in col3 is longer.

Comment: If your sample data included this row `2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla8'`, which row would you expect to see in the result set?  The `bla2` row or the `bla8` row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE  @TABLE_NAME TABLE(key1 INT, key2 INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TABLE_NAME 
SELECT 1,    2,    1,    10,   'bla'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    1,    2,    10,   'bla'
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2 ORDER BY LEN(col3) DESC) AS rn
FROM @TABLE_NAME 
)Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦════╗
║ key1 ║ key2 ║ col1 ║ col2 ║ col3 ║ rn ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬════╣
║    2 ║    2 ║    1 ║   10 ║ bla2 ║  1 ║
║    2 ║    1 ║    2 ║   10 ║ bla  ║  1 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩════╝
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/038e0e/10)

Comment: The query needs to take account of the length of the data in col3, so for rows that have the same values in cols 1 & 2 only one of them is returned and that is the one with the longest value in col3. The first line of the result set in my post shows col3 with a value of 'bla2' - this is what I really need.

Comment: @user3389019 I have updated my answer have a look now. and if it helped please accept it as your answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The analytic `row_number()` function fits the bill perfectly:

```
SELECT key1, key2, col1, col2, col3
FROM   (SELECT key1, key2, col1, col2, col3,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY key1, key2 ORDER BY LEN(col3) DESC) AS rn
        FROM   my_table) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: I think this will give row_number 1 to every row in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This works based on the small set of sample data.  However, the result set will have some duplicates if there are multiple rows with the same Co1/Col2 values and Col3 values that are all the same length.  For instance:

`2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla2'`

`2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla4'`

`2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla6'`

```
--A common table expression that represents the sample data from the OP.
WITH cteSampleData AS
(
    SELECT 1 Key1,    2 Key2,    1 Col1,    10 Col2,   'bla' Col3 UNION 
    SELECT 2,    2,    1,    10,   'bla2' UNION 
    SELECT 2,    1,    2,    10,   'bla'
),
--Another common table expression.  It returns unique combinations of col1 and col2 with the col3 value with the longest length.
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, MAX(LEN(Col3)) LongestCol3Val
    FROM cteSampleData
    GROUP BY Col1, Col2
)
SELECT c.*
FROM cteSampleData c
JOIN cte2
    ON cte2.Col1 = c.Col1
    AND cte2.Col2 = c.Col2
    AND cte2.LongestCol3Val = LEN(c.Col3)
```

Comment: This is also a good answer that works. Unfortunately I can only tick one response as the accepted "answer". Thanks, Paul

Comment: @user3389019: no biggie.  I appreciate the comment, though. :)